# how does celery stores task results in redis

Tags: python, redis, celery, task-queue

I am new to Python and Celery-Redis, so Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

I have been debugging a code base Which has structure like -

`TaskClass` -> Celery Task

`HandlerClass1, HandlerClass2` -> These are python classes extending Object class

The application creates `TaskClass` say `dumyTask` instance and `dumyTask` creates celery subtasks(I believe these subtasks are unique) say `dumySubTask1, dumySubTask2` by taking signatures of handler.

What I am not able to understand?

1) How does celery manages the results of `dumySubTask1, dumySubTask2` and `dumyTask`? I mean the results of `dumySubTask1` and `dumySubTask2` should be aggregated and given as result of `dumyTask`. How does Celery-Redis manage this?

2) once the task is executed how does celery stores tasks results in backend? I mean will the result of `dumySubTask1` and `dumySubTask2` be stored in backend and then results returned to `dumyTask` and then `dumyTask` return results to **QUEUE(Please correct if I am wrong)**?

3) Does Celery maintains Tasks and subtasks as **STACK**? Please see snapshot.[Task-SubTask Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsFpB.png)

Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

celery worker can invoke 'tasks' . This 'task' can have 'subtasks' which can be 'chained' together i.e invokes sequentially. 'chain' is the term specifically used in celery canvas guides. The result is then returned to the queue in redis.

celery worker are use to invoke 'independent tasks' mostly used for 'network use cases' i.e 'sending email','hitting url'

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it from the celery instance with

`task = app_celery.AsyncResult(task_id)`

### Full example - below

My `celery_worker.py` file is:

```
import os
import time

from celery import Celery
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(".env")

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND")


@celery.task(name="create_task")
def create_task(a, b, c):
    print(f"Executing create_task it will take {a}")
    [print(i) for i in range(100)]
    time.sleep(a)
    return b + c
```

I'm using FastAPI my endpoints are:

```
# To execute the task
@app.get("/sum")
async def root(sleep_time: int, first_number: int, second_number: int):
    process = create_task.delay(sleep_time, first_number, second_number)
    return {"process_id": process.task_id, "result": process.result}


# To get the task status and result
from celery_worker import create_task, celery
@app.get("/task/{task_id}")
async def check_task_status(task_id: str):
    task = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)
    return {"status": task.status, "result": task.result}
```

My `.env` file has:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
```